# Graduation of the Astronomy Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, graduation

The Astronomy Stack Exchange site is scheduled to graduate from Beta to a full site today, December 16th.

The moderator team would like to congratulate our entire user base for the contributions that made this graduation possible. The hard work and diligence in asking and answering questions thoroughly and respectfully has helped get us here. Specifically, graduation criteria has been based on the longevity of our site, the number of open questions, and the number of open questions that have at least one upvoted answer.

Anyone will have the option to self-nominate for new moderator elections, which may take place possibly as far out as 2023. Site customization, such as custom background and badge design isn't immediately planned but may be available in the future.

I love Astronomy SE for the wide variety of question topics and difficulty levels, the interesting and varied answers, and the dedication to hard science.

The corresponding META announcement is here: [Congratulations to the 58 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-58-sites-that-just-left-beta)

Again, Congratulations!!

Comment: The badge is gone... very different now.

Comment: [...I've been waiting for this moment, for all my life...](https://youtu.be/MN3x-kAbgFU?t=61)

Comment: Yay, happy graduation!

Answer (score 9):

Three thousand days later, it has finally come.

## CONGRATULATIONS!

Answer (score 3):

I had been waiting for this moment for a long time! :)

CONGRATULATIONS!

Answer (score 1):

CONGRATS!!! :D Sure took long enough xD

Also it graduated on my birthday that's fun lol.