# Site customization ideas?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, graduation, design

Just today, [we graduated from beta!](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/31410) :D

@ConnorGarcia notes in his post:

> Site customization, such as custom background and badge design isn't immediately planned but may be available in the future.

I'd like to just put out a place where any suggestions for site banner, badge design, or background could be accepted as proposals. Again, congratulations everyone on site graduation!

Comment: Keep in mind that SE has said that site design takes a lot of resources, and there are still many older sites (such as History) that have no custom design yet either, so it may be several years before site design is an option and at that point design standards may have changed.

Comment: According to the official announcement - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/236563 - site redesigns aren't happening at the moment.  It may be a while for any such suggestions to be implemented.