# Is 500 reputations enough to be able to "cast close & reopen votes"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I have just asked 4 questions here, and thanks to other members two of them were received very well.

Now I have surpassed 500 reputations and I have received a new privilege "Casting close & reopen votes".

But is 500 reputations enough so that this privilege is granted? I mean I am still new here and I have to be experienced more in asking good questions (one of my questions isn't received very well). In other words, how can a member who isn't experienced enough yet, know and decide which post deserves a close?

In contrast, I have a reputation of 609 in English language learners SE, but I haven't been granted this privilege yet there.

I personally think that the privilege of splitting the score should be prior to casting close votes.

Comment: Note: privileges with reputation levels can be found here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The threshold for various privileges varies between sites, depending on [the phase the site is in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/274942). Sites in the beta phase have lower reputation thresholds for various privileges. Astronomy [recently left the beta phase](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/824/2153), as English Language Learners had already done, but [for various reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/274942), the thresholds have not been raised to the levels they are on sites that had previously left beta, which is why [the ability to cast close votes](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) only requires 500 reputation here.

You could argue that this is a bit low; on the other hand, most folks take a while to get to 500. I'd guess that the typical reputation point gain on a new user's post is around 30-40 points. Most people who gain close/reopen privileges have enough time to get acquainted with the site and its scope to properly use them. (Citation: We haven't had any major issues with that over the past 8+ years!)

Comment: Excellent answer! I agree completely.